Understanding Milnor $\bar{\mu}$-Invariants
I find Milnor's $\bar{\mu}$-invariants a bit confusing. My understanding of their calculation is as follows:

draw the link diagram, label the arcs
write down Wirtinger presentation of the link group $\pi_1$
obtain the presentation $\pi_1/\Gamma_k\pi_1=\langle x_1,\dots,x_n \mid [x_1,\lambda_1],\dots,[x_n,\lambda_n],\Gamma_k\pi_1 \rangle$ for the quotient of $\pi_1$ with the $k$-th member of its lower central series $\Gamma_k\pi_1$.
calculate the magnus expansion of the $\lambda_i$ to get power series $\lambda_i=1+\sum \mu(j_1\dots j_s i)\kappa_{j_1}\dots \kappa_{j_s}$.
call $I=j_1\dots j_s i$ and calculate the greatest common divisor $\Delta(I)$ of the $\mu(I')$, where $I'$ goes through all the proper subsequences of $I$.
now we get the isotopy invariants $\bar{\mu}(j_1\dots j_si)=\mu(j_1\dots j_s i)\bmod \Delta(j_1\dots j_si)$.

Things I don't understand

how do we turn the Wirtinger presentiation into the presentation of $\pi_1/\Gamma_k\pi_1$? Is there an obvious systematic way, or is this in general hard to do?
are these $\lambda_i$ unique? Probably not, but they still lead to the same invariants?
since $\lambda_i$ is a power series we could in general have infinitely many $\bar{\mu}$. For a specific $k$, only terms of degree $\leq k-1$ are actually invariants but $k$ can be chosen arbitrarily large. Which $\bar{\mu}$ am I interested in? If I want to show that two arbitrary links are distinct, is it decidable whether all of their $\bar{\mu}$-invariants are equal?
I have seen people not ignore the $\bmod \Delta(j_1\dots j_si)$ but surely this is really needed to make it an invariant?

The definition of these invariants feels very arbitrary and I don't really see why they work.
I am interested in Brunnian links. There is an easy way to "write down the link diagram" for a simple Brunnian link as a word in the free group. I would like to use $\bar{\mu}$-invariants to show that these links are actually brunnian (i.e. non-trivial with trivial sublinks).
I have seen that Milnor calculated $\bar{\mu}$-invariants for some Brunnnian links to show that they are non-trivial, but I could not find a source where $\bar{\mu}$-invariants were calculated for a more general class of Brunnian links (i.e. simple ones).
